# Validate RegEx pattern in PowerShell

Tags: regex, powershell

Is it possible to validate pattern before creating RegEx object in PowerShell?

```
$Pattern = "[A-Z]{1,3" # Pattern is invalid
$Regex = [regex]::new($Pattern) # this throw an exception
```

Let say that I have XML file with configuration and there are fields with pattern which will be used in the script. If pattern is not correct I'm getting an error which I would like to avoid.

Comment: Use [`try { [regex]::new($Pattern) } catch { <# error handling code goes here #> }`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_try_catch_finally?view=powershell-7.4)

Comment: Yes, that's something which I would like to avoid and reason why I post this question

Comment: What _do_ you want to do? You obviously can't go ahead with whatever you were going to use `$Regex` for, so what should happen instead?

Comment: There is no inherent pattrn validation function for regexs. Error Catching is pretty much your one option.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to **avoid dealing with the exception** (which you could do with `try` / `catch`, as Mathias shows in a comment), you can use the **[`-as`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Type_Operators) operator**, which *attempts* conversion to a given RHS type, and quietly returns `$null` if that fails:

```
$valid = $null -ne ($regex = $pattern -as [regex])
```

- `$valid` then contains a Boolean (`$true` or `$false`) that indicates whether `$pattern` contains a valid regex.
- `$regex` then either contains a `[regex]` instance based on the pattern, or `$null` if the pattern isn't valid.

  - If all you want to do is to validate the pattern itself, remove the `$regex =` part